# The meaning of "Watch for a smooth!"

Tags: meaning

> SHOVE off from the wharf-edge! Steady!
>  
>   **Watch for a smooth!** Give way!
>  
>   **If she feels the lop already** 
>   She'll stand on her head in the bay.
>   It's ebb–it's dusk–it's blowing–
>   The shoals are a mile
>   of white,
>   But (snatch her along! ) we're going
>   To find our
>   master to-night.

This is from  "Song of the Red War-Boat" by Kipling.

I am glad if some one kindly teach me the meaning of  two lines below.

Watch for a smooth!
 
If she feels the lop already

Comment: From [the full OED,](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182756?rskey=WAHS6d&result=1#eid) ***smooth*** (noun, nautical) *A stretch of comparatively smooth or calm water in a rough sea.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Anyone who has kippled much is aware of the author's fondness for nautical arcana, but this one made me look twice. Did you know it without peeking?

Comment: @P. E. Dant: It's hard to be sure with things like this, but I certainly don't recall ever coming across this usage before. On the other hand, given the context, I was more or less expecting the definition I found above. If I hadn't immediately seen a subdefinition headed **Naut** on the first screen of definitions, I'd very likely have searched the entire multi-screen webpage for those four letters. Same with ***lop*** - which I did also search for, but it turned out that was *really* easy to find because it's a different etymology, so OED have a completely separate (short) entry for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure, but I'm guessing that "Watch for a smooth" means "Don't launch the boat when a big wave is coming," and the "lop" refers to a wave hitting the boat as it's being launched. (Therefore, the essence is: Be careful! If the boat gets hit by a big wave as it's being launched, it might tip over – i.e., "stand on its head")

In any case, I don't think it's day-to-day parlance (at least, not that I'm aware of – not even at a marina or wharf). It sounds very dated.

For what it's worth, the OED lists 8 different meanings of *lop* as a noun; one of them is a Nautical term, meaning, "A state of the sea in which the waves are short and lumpy." There are a few example usages provided (all from the 19th century):

- There being a ‘lop’ on, the boat lurched to windward.
- Quite a ‘lop’ of a sea gets up, but these battleships take no heed of it.
- There was too much ‘lop’.

Comment: @JR  Thank so much,for your detailed and kind answer!! Hiroshi